# np.random.choice в python

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста, как работает вот этот кусок кода: `np.random.choice(range(n*m)`

```
import numpy as np
    n = 5 #строки
    m = 5 #столбцы
    p = 11 #кол-во частиц
    Z = np.zeros((n,m)) #создание двумерного массива размерности nxm и заполнение его нулями
    np.put(Z, np.random.choice(range(n*m), p, replace=False), 1)
```

Comment: На самом деле вам нужно узнать, что делает range(m*n). К координатам это не имеет ни малейшего отношения

Comment: range же позволяет генерировать ряд чисел в рамках заданного диапазона, не совсем пойму как работает такое произведение

Comment: (m*n)  здесь имеется ввиду произведение.

Comment: Так и работает,  что m*n это просто  напросто число.

Comment: тогда вопрос, для того чтобы заменить определенные элементы массива заданными значениями  нам же нужно знать индекс двумерного массива,т.е Z[n,m], разве не так?

Comment: range генератор. создается последовательность от 0 до 24. Вот так 0,1,2 .... 22, 23, 24 Все индексы 5x5

Comment: далее с помощью np.random.choice мы получаем рандомный элемент из этой последовательности, например 13, и что оно нам даёт, мы же не знаем значения "строки-столбца",чтобы определить куда втолкнуть единичку в моём случае, именно этот нюанс меня беспокоит

Comment: В этом случае вас  интересует работа функции numpy.put :)

Comment: если я правильно понял, то в функции numpy.put индексы массива целыми числами обозначаются, а не как A[i][j],верно?)

Comment: вопрос закрыт!!